# How do I create a pem file from id_rsa.pub?

Tags: ssh, encryption, aws

I have `id_rsa`, `id_rsa.pub` and `known_hosts` in `.ssh`; but how do I create a `.pem` file for [AWS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html#how-to-generate-your-own-key-and-import-it-to-aws)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create anything, the contents of `id_rsa.pub` are what you should provide when asked for a public key.

As it says:

> Amazon EC2 accepts the following formats:
>
> - OpenSSH public key format (the format in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys)
> - Base64 encoded DER format
> - SSH public key file format as specified in RFC4716

`id_rsa.pub` is already in a format suitable for `authorized_keys`.

Comment: thanks, I was on the wrong web interface.  why do they say key *pair* when only the .pub key is imported?